# Organizing and plotting data from machine taking multiple readings

Tags: excel, graph, plot, reorganize

I am trying to organize a workbook generated from data retrieved from an analog pressure meter. It takes a reading of different pressures at different times and spits out a row in an excel table. For instance a couple rows will look like

```
[series 1][time 1][data]
[series 2][time 1][data]
[series 1][time 2][data]
```

How do I plot this data on a line graph so that each series is plotted on a separate line?
I would like to know a general way to do this so I can record a macro that does it automatically. Thank you for your help

Comment: I guess it isn't a programming question, save for the fact I would like to create a macro to do this automatically. And the reason I don't think that is the best way is because there are almost 70000 data points and a number of different series. I'm wondering if there is a way to make excel recognize that the first column is the data series, column 2 is the time value, and column 3 is the data value and plot it automatically.

Comment: It seems like you want a PivotChart (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-pivotchart-HA102919712.aspx).